# how to remove space at the bottom for dynamic contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am designing a page where bottom part of a div should touch the end of the page that is no bottom margin or padding so I put height of the main div as

```
 $(function() {
     $('.divMain').css({'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'});

     $(window).resize(function() {
         $('.divMain').css({'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'});
     });
 });
```

My HTML is :

```
<div class="divMain">
    <table id="eduGrid"></table>
</div>
```

where `"eduGrid"` is generated dynamically(Bootstrap).

Initially its work fine but I have some contents in that div that can be added at the user end(add new education etc) so that contents are moving outside the main div and its looking wired.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: Write sample code for the div

Comment: Where should the overflowing content go? Do you want it to hide or do you want the page to scroll?

Comment: I want to show all the contents without scroll-bar and that contents should be inside the main div

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto`?

Comment: @Jack..  I have tried all the values for overflow property but its not solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but I have found a solution for this problem..I have changed my function body as :

```
        $(function() {
            $('.divMain').css({'min-height': (($(window).height()) - 70) + 'px'});

            $(window).resize(function() {
                $('.divMain').css({'min-height': (($(window).height()) - 70) + 'px'});
            });
        });
```

So now initially main div have minimum height as browser height and when content of main div got increased then height of main div will also increase.

Answer (score 0):

Check this for full screen result - http://fiddle.jshell.net/DRRsn/1/show/light/

Check this for fiddle code - http://jsfiddle.net/DRRsn/1/

**CSS**

```
html,body{width:100%;height:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:0;padding:0;}
div{background:blue;}
table{background:pink;height:100%;;width:50%}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divMain">
<table id="eduGrid"></table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.divMain').css({'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'});
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.divMain').css({'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'});
    });
});
```

Hope this is what u were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this isn't what you're looking for - I think it is? - but if you wish the 'divMain' to take 100% of the browser window's width & height, you can do this with CSS - simply by making it a position:absolute <div>

```
.divMain {
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;
}
```

So by default it will have 100% height, but if the <table> content is higher than the page, divMain will stretch out.

(Tested on Chrome)